# How to use SPSS to perform a 2-tailed Binomial test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, binomial-distribution

Supposing we have 0,1 labeled samples,   when I using SPSS to perform a binomial test, and to see if case 0 and case 1 has equal proportion(0.5), the software automatically pick a two-tailed binominal test, but the problem is how can I perform a test to see if the case 1 proportion equals to 0.1 or not.

Since, when I select the testing proportion to 0.1,  the software automatically switches to 1-tailed binomial test, and this will give me an alterative hypothesis like how the case 1 propotion likely to be less than 0.1 (and a p value).

How can I switch the test to two-tailed test when the testing proportion is not equals to 0.5?

Anyone can help?

Comment: In the case that the sample is in the direction of the alternative, e.g. 15/20 and the alternative is greater than 0.5, you can simply divide the 2-tailed p-value SPSS spits out by two. In the obverse case though, e.g. 5/20, and the alternative is greater than 0.5 I'm not sure how to calculate that p-value off-hand.

Comment: maybe this can help http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203693/exact-binomial-test-p-values/203698#203698